# Prolog beginner (Avoid using semi-colon and if else statements)

Tags: prolog

So I want to create a predicate that will take a list of numbers and sum up the squares of each entry IF either they are divisible by 5 or 3.

So if I have the list [6, 7, 9, 10], it will return a sum of

```
6^2+9^2+10^2
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
sumsquared([], 0).


sumsquared([Head|Tail], Sum):-

   divisible(Head),

   sumsquared(Tail, Sumofrest),

   Sum is Head*Head + Sumofrest.



divisible(Head):-

   0 is Head mod 3.

divisible(Head):-

   0 is Head mod 5.
```

This code works for [3, 6, 9, 10] and things like that but when we have a list say [2, 3, 6, 9, 10], prolog will give it a false. This is because I have divisible(Head) in my code. I'm trying to look for a way around this without using an "if-else statement" or a ";" in Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. A few things have been missing in your code.

First, you only handled the "divisible" case. So if one list item is not divisible, the entire goal fails.

Next, to express `non_divisible` without using `->` or `;` apply 
De Morgan's laws to get to:

```
divisible(X) :- X mod 3 =:= 0.
divisible(X) :- X mod 5 =:= 0.

non_divisible(X) :- X mod 3 =\= 0,
                    X mod 5 =\= 0.

sumsquared([], 0).
sumsquared([Head|Tail], Sum):-
   divisible(Head),
   sumsquared(Tail, Sumofrest),
   Sum is Head*Head + Sumofrest.
sumsquared([Head|Tail], Sum) :-     % new clause
   non_divisible(Head),
   sumsquared(Tail, Sum).
```

Let's test the query you gave again:

```
?- sumsquared([6,7,9,10], Sum).
Sum = 217 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second sumsquare/2 clause covers the case where the first element of the list is divisible. You need to add a third clause to cover the case where it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
One solution, not tail-recursive (meaning it will overflow the stack given a sufficiently long list).

    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three( []     , 0 ) .
    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three( [X|Xs] , R ) :-
      compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three( Xs , T ) ,
      transform(X,N) ,
      R is T + N.

    transform( X , X ) :- 0 =:= X mod 5 + X mod 3 , ! .
    transform( X , N ) :- N is X*X .

Transformed into tail-recursion:

    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three(Xs,R) :-
      compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three(Xs,0,R)
      .

    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three( []     , R , R ) .
    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three( [X|Xs] , T , R ) :-
      transform(X,N) ,
      T1 is T+N,
      compute_sum_of_list_squaring_multiples_of_five_or_three( Xs , T1, R ).

    transform( X , X ) :- 0 =:= X mod 5 + X mod 3 , ! .
    transform( X , N ) :- N is X*X .

A generic version:

    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_certain_multiples( Xs , Ds , R ) :-
      compute_sum_of_list_squaring_certain_multiples( Xs , Ds , 0 , R )
      .

    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_certain_multiples( []     , _  , R , R ) .   % when we get to the end of the list, the accumulator has the desired value. Unify it with the result.
    compute_sum_of_list_squaring_certain_multiples( [X|Xs] , Ds , T , R ) :-  % otherwise...
      transform(X,Ds,N) ,                                                     % - transform X (squaring X if divisible an item in Ds, leaving it alone otherwise)
      T1 is T+N ,                                                             % - add the transformed value to the accumulator
      compute_sum_of_list_squaring_certain_multiples(Xs,Ds,T1,R)              % - and recurse down.
      .                                                                       %

    transform( X , []    ,X  ) .              % no target dividends? leave it alone.
    transform( X , [D|_] , N ) :-             % otherwise...
      0 =: X mod D ,                          % - if X is divisible by the current dividend,
      !,                                      % - cut off the alternatives,
      N is X*X                                % - square X and unify with the result.
      .                                       %
    transform(X,[_|Ds],N) :-                  % Finally (X is not divisible by the dividend in question)...
      transform(X,Ds,N)                       % - uust recurse down and keep looking.
      .                                       %
```

You should able to invoke the above thus:

```
compute_sum_of_list_squaring_certain_multiples( [1,2,3,4,5,6] , [3,5] , R ) .
```

And get

```
R = 41
```

Comment: `transform/2` is not steadfast.